# How to show multiple master record fields in detail table?

Tags: database, delphi, relationship, ado, c++builder

I use ADO components (Delphi/C++ Builder) and let's say I have a simple one-to-many relationship like in the following picture:

[image: one to many relationship]

Here it is obvious that `CustNo` is the primary key in the first table, and it's value is showed in the detail table. Is it possible, and how to show additional master record fields in the detail table? For example, I would also like to show `Company` field in the detail table, and not just `CustNo`.

Comment: It seems which you are using the `TAdoTable` components, just replace those components by `TAdoQuery` , and then write a SQL according to your needs.

Comment: I'm interested how to do it with TADOTable if possible.

Comment: Ok, then try using a [Calculated field](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Defining_a_Calculated_Field).